# Use of "ci" in "ci vediamo"

Tags: grammar

I understand that *ci* can be used for a number of purposes. Indirect/direct object for us, place adverb, demonstrative pronoun, reflexive pronoun, part of idiomatic verb like *metterci*.

I do not understand which is these applies to the use of *ci* in the phrase *ci vediamo*.

Can you help explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

La particella ci, è usata anche con verbi riflessivi o pronominali, e nella costruzione impersonale. Ad es:

> Fate i bravi, altrimenti ci arrabbiamo!

> Ci si vede più tardi

[(Treccani.it)](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ci_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/)

Comment: The _ci_ in these examples are used differently from the _ci_ in the OP's phrase. _Ci arrabbiamo_, for instance, is an example of an _intransitivo pronominale_, which _ci vediamo_ isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's still the direct object there (that happens to be the same as the subject). The meaning normally is the reciprocal "we see each other" and not the reflexive "we see ourselves", but we still see "us", don't we?

Answer (score 1):

Among the uses you mention in the question, the relevant one is that of direct object: here, more or less, *ci* = “us”. In fact, the phrase *ci vediamo* might be slightly ambiguous in Italian.

The most immediate meaning is “we see each other”, especially as a form to say goodbye (“see ya”). But, within a suitable sentence, it might also mean “we see ourselves” (in a mirror, say, or figuratively, we see ourselves in some role or situation).

The former, most obvious interpretation is known in Italian as a *riflessivo reciproco*; the latter is a simple *riflessivo*.